# Empty tail for tags

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, design, google-chrome

Opening [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4682/176217) in Chrome on Android displays strange tag borders (different padding on the sides):

> [image]

Open in incognito mode looks fine:

> [image]

Seems this is due moderator (10k) privilege.

> [image]

- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1635123498b3d)

Can't repro on another Android (5.1.1) with same Chrome version.

Comment: no repro on Chrome 56 / Win10

Comment: @rene desktop or iOS version also OK. Only this post, and only on Android.

Comment: That is strange then. I doubt there is anything SE can do about it then. no?

Comment: @rene dunno. Such bug is weird and unique - this is its feature :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything special in  its raw source either. Weird indeed.

Comment: @rene probably you need mod privilege here. Post updated.

Comment: Yes, I definitely need mod privileges here, thanks ;)

Comment: @rene I meant on Russian SO :)

Comment: There is a mobile view for mobile devices. Weird design is to be expected for the full site theme on mobile devices, so not really a bug. (i.e. will be declined - simply use the mobile theme.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard nevertheless my phone has a bigger screen resolution then my PC. Mobile theme (i.e. mobile-web, as fas as I understand you) is more restricted, so I need to use full-web on mobile device from time to time.

Comment: Of course, you can use full web theme, it will work, but what I'm saying is that the design was not made for mobile devices, no matter what's their screen size.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what I can't understand yet is what's a root of such weird bug. I even can't repro on landscape mode if I do refresh ot the page. But if I do rotate (without refresh) from portrait mode to landscape I see same issue.

Comment: Dunno... my own experience is also horrible - fonts in random size, colors sometimes differ... but in mobile theme all is OK.

Comment: I can reproduce this, but I doubt there's anything we can do. Tags use extremely basic CSS that's been around for ages. It seems related to the "edit tags" link that appears to the right for 10k+ users, where Chrome seems to be resizing the tags to fit the space left by hiding the element. This isn't proper behavior and should be considered a bug in Chrome for Android.

Comment: @animuson probably this could be fixed on SE side after submitting [my FR](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/176217) on translation. To test we need to upload transifex DB and rebuid site.

Comment: @alexolut It has nothing to do with the translation of the text. It does this on Meta Stack Overflow too, using the English version. Chrome is just bugged.

Comment: @animuson can't test English version. Not a mod yet :) I thought the problem is in the text length.